# Why is it bad practice to ask for full name in a form?

Tags: html, forms

In many many forms you see separate inputs for first and last name. I assume that asking for a users full name in one input is bad practice because you cannot rely on simply splitting the string by spaces to get the first and last names.

Now I think about it i'm not sure if this would be a problem, can anyone shed any light on whether this is good or bad practice and if it is bad to ask for full name in a single input, why is it bad.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about UI and UX and not programming. It's also asking for opinion. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you have a first name that is split by white space, how are you going to tell where the first name ends, and the last name begins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you need to address a customer by Last Name, First Name you're screwed. Sorting becomes a problem, etc.

It's very little extra effort to ask for each separately even if you don't think it's useful now. But to go back and do it is very problematic. Data atomization is important.